# Node.js Azure sdk - getting the Virtual Machine state

Tags: node.js, azure, sdk, azure-virtual-machine

I've started to look into the azure sdk for node.js (link below) and interestingly enough I've hit a wall in what I'd image would be one of the most common tasks one would want to achieve using Azure's REST endpoints which is checking the status of a virtual machine.

I can easily get a list of all machine, or one in particular but the response from this services don't include the current status of the VM (running,stopped etc.)

There's absolutely no info out there regarding this particular scenario in the docos or the web other than a blog post (https://github.com/Azure/azure-xplat-cli/issues/2565) which is actually in regards of a different library.

Please not that I'm using the azure-arm-compute library which is part of the Node.js azure sdk.

Any help would be very much appreciated

github repo: https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-node

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To get Virtual Machine statuses, please use function [`get(resourceGroupName, vmName, optionsopt, optionalCallbackopt)`](http://azure.github.io/azure-sdk-for-node/azure-arm-compute/latest/VirtualMachines.html#get), and pass the vaule `{expand: 'instanceView'}` as the options parameter.

```
var msRestAzure = require('ms-rest-azure');
var computeManagementClient = require('azure-arm-compute');

// Interactive Login
// It provides a url and code that needs to be copied and pasted in a browser and authenticated over there. If successful, 
// the user will get a DeviceTokenCredentials object.
msRestAzure.interactiveLogin(function(err, credentials) {
  var client = new computeManagementClient(credentials, 'ed0caab7***');

  client.virtualMachines.get('<resourceGroupName>', '<vmName>', {expand: 'instanceView'}, function(err, result, request, response) {
    if (err) console.log(err);
    console.log(result.instanceView);
  });
});
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks Aaron. This looks promising. I'll have a look later today and mark it as answered. Btw, where did you get the info from? I went through the docos and couldn't find anything. Clearly I didn't do a good job!

Comment: As @singhkays mentioned in a blog post that you provided above, we need to call the instance view API on each VM to get the VM state. After having the API doc (http://azure.github.io/azure-sdk-for-node/azure-arm-compute/latest/VirtualMachines.html#get) scrolled, I notice that we can include the value: `instanceView`, in property `expand`. Then I tried.

Comment: Great. Must have missed it. Thanks for the help!